# Creating a multi-select grid of buttons in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: size side bar]

I am trying to implement a grid of buttons in React.js that has the above look.

## Expected Behavior

Each button when clicked toggles the `selected` class on the `SizeButton`.

The button in the above image that is selected is the one with the 'X'.

## What is *Actually* Occurring

Each button when clicked **doesn't** toggles the `selected` class on the `SizeButton`.

*The way I believed this is implemented is a wrapping component that contains many individual button components. The wrapping component would contain state information pertaining to the state of each button.*

**The above image is what I am expecting, but not actually happening.**

### SizeSideBar.js

```
class SizeSideBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            query: ''
        }

        this.setSize = this.setSize.bind(this);
    }

    setSize(size) {
        this.setState({
            query: size.toUpperCase(),
        }, () => {
            if (this.state.query.length > 0) {
                this.props.history.push(`?size=${size.toUpperCase()}`)
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Size</h3>
                <hr />
                <div>
                    <SizeButton size="x" setSize={this.setSize} />
                    <SizeButton size="xxs" setSize={this.setSize} />
                    <SizeButton size="xs" setSize={this.setSize} />
                    <SizeButton size="s" setSize={this.setSize} />
                    <SizeButton size="m" setSize={this.setSize} />
                    <SizeButton size="l" setSize={this.setSize} />
                    <SizeButton size="xl" setSize={this.setSize} />
                    <SizeButton size="xxl" setSize={this.setSize} />
                    <SizeButton size="2xl" setSize={this.setSize} />
                    <SizeButton size="3xl" setSize={this.setSize} />
                    <SizeButton size="4xl" setSize={this.setSize} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

### SizeButton.js

```
const SizeButton = (props) => {
    const { size, setSize } = props

    const selectedSize = getPageQueries(window.location.search).size
    const isSelected = selectedSize === size

    return (
        <button
            id="sizeButton"
            className={isSelected ? 'selected' : ''}
            onClick={() => {
                setSize(size);
            }}
        >
            {size.toUpperCase()}
        </button>
    )
}
```

### getPageQueries()

```
export const getPageQueries = (url) => {
    const arr = url.slice(1).split(/&|=/); // remove the "?", "&" and "="
    let params = {};

    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2){
       const key = arr[i], value = arr[i + 1];
       params[key] = value ; // build the object = { limit: "10", page:"1", status:"APPROVED" }
    }

    return params;
};
```

Comment: And... where is a question? It works not as you expected, we don't know what you expected and what you get.

Comment: @AndriiGolubenko Sorry, I justed added that piece of information.

Comment: could you make `console.log` in SizeButton and check what value you will get in `selectedSize` after a click. And why you couldn't pass value from 'state.query' to SizeButton? Why do you need to use a location for this?

Comment: Your `state.queries` should be a map of selected sizes, pass an `isSelected` prop where the size is a key into that map. Toggle class on that prop.

Comment: I think each button should be an object, with `isSeected`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let each button manage it's own selected state, on click it will set it's own color.

```
class SizeButton extends React.Component {

  state = {
    isSelected: false,
  }

  setSelected = () => {
    this.setState({
      isSelected: !this.state.isSelected
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { size, setSize } = this.props;
    return (
      <button
        id="sizeButton"
        className={this.state.isSelected ? 'selected' : ''}
        onClick={() => {
          this.setSelected();
          setSize(size);
        }}
      >
        {size.toUpperCase()}
      </button>
    )
  }
}
```

**OR**

Create an array of sizes object, like `{size: 'X', isSelected: false }`, and loop through this array check if `isSelected` is true.

```
state = {
 query: [
   {size: 'X', isSelected: false },
   {size: 'xxs', isSelected: false },
   {size: 'xs', isSelected: false }
 ],
}
```

Then render the sizes like

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Size</h3>
      <hr />
      <div />
      {this.state.queries.map((button, key) => (
        <SizeButton
          key={key}
          size={button.size}
          isSelected={button.isSelected}
          setSize={this.setSize}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}


const SizeButton = (props) => {
const { size, setSize, isSelected } = props

  return (
      <button
        id="sizeButton"
        className={isSelected ? 'selected' : ''}
        onClick={() => {
            setSize(size);
        }}
      >
        {size.toUpperCase()}
      </button>
   )
}
```

**DEMO**

```css
.selected {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class SizeButton extends React.Component {

  state = {
    isSelected: false,
  }

  setSelected = () => {
    this.setState({
      isSelected: !this.state.isSelected
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { size, setSize } = this.props;
    return (
      <button
        id="sizeButton"
        className={this.state.isSelected ? 'selected' : ''}
        onClick={() => {
          this.setSelected();
          setSize(size);
        }}
      >
        {size.toUpperCase()}
      </button>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {

  }

  setSize = (size) => {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Size</h3>
        <hr />
        <div>
          <SizeButton size="x" setSize={this.setSize} />
          <SizeButton size="xxs" setSize={this.setSize} />
          <SizeButton size="xs" setSize={this.setSize} />
          <SizeButton size="s" setSize={this.setSize} />
          <SizeButton size="m" setSize={this.setSize} />
          <SizeButton size="l" setSize={this.setSize} />
          <SizeButton size="xl" setSize={this.setSize} />
          <SizeButton size="xxl" setSize={this.setSize} />
          <SizeButton size="2xl" setSize={this.setSize} />
          <SizeButton size="3xl" setSize={this.setSize} />
          <SizeButton size="4xl" setSize={this.setSize} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

</script>
```